# How to determine sample size for mixed effects design

Tags: mixed-model, anova, interaction, statistical-power

I'm designing a study with one within subject factor (intervention 1: baseline vs increased), a between subjects factor (intervention 2: present vs absent), and another between-subjects factor (education level: lower vs higher).

I'm interested in the main effects and:

Interaction between intervention 1 * education level

Interaction between intervention 2 * education level

I was planning to use a linear mixed model with participant as a random effect. I know an alternative might be a mixed ANOVA but I think the linear mixed model is preferable

**My concern is how to estimate a sample size for this study.**

I imagine least powerful test would be the Interaction between the between subject factors, so should I power for this test?

I've read about simulations but I'm not familiar with them.

Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

What software are you using to estimate the sample size. I would assume that GPower has the ability to calculate your sample size.

I would argue tho that you could just compute the power for this test considering a linear regression with 5 Independent Variables. Because your ANOVA could be described as a linear regression with 3 main effects plus two Interactions.

Edit:
Here it is claimed you need 16x larger sample size for interactions
https://statmodeling.stat.columbia.edu/2018/03/15/need-16-times-sample-size-estimate-interaction-estimate-main-effect/